# Node-Express What's the process in JWT authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am currently using jet to authenticate users.
In my user.routes I have also a router.param() to load the user and append it to the request.
Is the jet control on GET user/:userId protecting also the router.param() load (is the checking does before?) 
or should also protect the router.param() ?

The problem is JWT is setting req.user to:

```
  { username: 'johndoe', iat: 1496329757 }
```

And the router.param() is searching and should load the user into req.user too !!
but it does not ...

if I debug req?user at the beginning of the addRole function, I still get the

```
{ username: 'johndoe', iat: 1496329757 }
```

*NOTE: not sure the Title reflects correctly my question... suggestions welcome*

**user.route.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';
import validate from 'express-validation';
import paramValidation from '../../../config/param-validation';
import userCtrl from '../controllers/user.controller';
import config from '../../../config/config';

const router = express.Router(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap
...
/** GET /api/users/:userId - Get user */
router.route('/:userId')
  /** GET /api/users/:userId - Get user */
  .get(expressJwt({ secret: config.jwtSecret }), userCtrl.get);
  ...
/** Load user when API with userId route parameter is hit */
router.param('userId', userCtrl.load);
```

**user.controller.js**

```
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import APIError from '../../helpers/APIError';
import User from '../../models/user.model';

/**
 * Load user and append to req.
 */
function load(req, res, next, id) {
  User.get(id)
    .then((user) => {
      req.user = user; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
      next();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        if (e.name === 'CastError') {
          const err = new APIError('Cast Error', httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, true);
          next(err);
        } else {
          const err = new APIError('User not found', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, true);
          next(err);
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, modifying the load() function in the controller:

```
function load(req, res, next, id) {
  User.get(id)
    .then((user) => {
      req.userData = user; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
      next();
    })
```